# Bootstrap Card Footer Not Formatting to Second Row Correctly

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am getting frustrated with trying to use Bootstrap to format a card footer. What I am trying to achieve is to get rating stars on top row of footer and title and price on bottom row of footer.

```
<div className="card-footer d-flex  mb-0">

        <div className="row">
          <div className="col">
            <Rating _id={_id} />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="row justify-content-between">
          <div className="col">
            <p className="align-self-center mb-0 ">
              {title}
            </p>
            <h5 className="text-blue font-itealic mb-0"><span className="mr-1">$</span>{price}</h5>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

This image shows the incorrect result of my code.

[image]

The next image shows what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

By the way, I am using React if it matters. Any help would certainly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let me see if i can help you. Try using css grid on that footer like this:

```
<div className="card-footer d-flex  mb-0">
  <div className="foot-grid">

    <div className="rating">
        <Rating _id={_id} />
    </div>
    <div className="title">
       <p className="text-center">{title}</p>
    </div>
    <div className="price">
      <h5 className="text-blue font-italic mb-0"><span className="mr-1">$</span>{price}</h5>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

And your css for that would be this:

```
.foot-grid{ 
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
   padding: 0 1rem;
}
.foot-grid>.rating{
   grid-column: 1/-1;
}
.foot-grid>.title{ text-align: left; }
.foot-grid>.price{ text-align: right; }
```

Edit: What's inside `<Rating />` first wrapper is a div element? ?

That should be enough, i hope it helps you out. If not, just tell me to edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you @benjamin. That worked great. Would you mind explaining the CSS. In particular, please explain .foot-grid and .foot-grid.rating. The Rating is a React component that displays the rating stars.

Comment: .foot-grid, .rating, title, and .price are css class selector. Those names were arbitrarily selected, i just thought those would be good names.

Now, how does it work? 

First, .foot-grid

display grid will make that container a grid container, which allows to create multi-rows and multi-columns grids natively. `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr)` is same as `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr` which separes every row on 2 equal width columns. and then, `padding: 0 1rem` is optional just to create an inner margin.

Comment: Any direct child from a grid container, will be able to use some features that will allow you to place them wherever you want. By default, every element will be placed on every column following the code's order, and then will jump to next row if there are no more columns available. So, i use `.foot-grid>.rating{ grid-column: 1/-1 }` to tell .rating specifically to take up the full row. Then, .title and .price will follow the regular flow, so i don't need to tell them where i want them to be (i could, but i don't need to).

Comment: Finally, `.foot-grid>.title{ text-align: left; }` and `.foot-grid>.price{ text-align: right; }` is just regular text alignment since .title and .price contains text-based elements. NOTE: i'm selectin `.foot-grid>.rating´ and `.foot-grid>.title´ aaand `.foot-grid>.price´ to make sure this does not affect any other element with .rating, .title or .price classes, but it would also work without `.foot-grid>` although i wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it will help you

```
<div className="card-footer d-flex  mb-0">

    <div className="row">
      <div className="col">
        <Rating _id={_id} />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div className="row justify-content-between">
      <div className="col">
        <p className="align-self-center mb-0 ">
          {title}
          <span className="text-blue font-itealic mb-0"><span className="mr-1">$</span>{price}</span>
        </p>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I tried your solution and I did not see a difference.